# Code within try block being ignored, why?

Tags: java, try-catch

I'm new to programming and have been trying to learn the basics of Java by writing a simple program that will apply a Caesar shift to some text. I've been able to do this and so far what my code does is this:

1. Asks the user how many units they would like to shift the text by.
2. Prompts the user to enter some text.
3. Applies a Caesar shift by that many units and prints the result.

Here is the working code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Shift{

public static void main(String[] args){

    //This will scan for user input.
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Shift by this many characters (0-25): ");
    int shift = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();//Skips over the whitespace after the integer
    System.out.print("Enter Text: ");
    String input = sc.nextLine();
    sc.close();

    //Initialise a character array containing every letter in the alphabet. 
    char[] alphabetArray = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m',
                            'n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    char[] alphabetArrayCaps = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M',
                                'N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};

    //Initialise the two variables that will be used in the next step.
    char[] constantArray = input.toCharArray();
    char[] output = input.toCharArray();

    //Implement a Caesar shift by the given number of units.
    for (int i=0; i < constantArray.length; i++){ //cycles through the user input character by character
        for (int j=0; j <= 25; j++){ //cycles through the alphabet
            if (constantArray[i] == alphabetArray[j]){
                    output[i] = alphabetArray[(j+shift)%26];
            }
            else if (constantArray[i] == alphabetArrayCaps[j]){
                        output[i] = alphabetArrayCaps[(j+shift)%26];
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(output);
    }
    }
```

The problem with this code is that when the user is asked to input an integer, there will be an exception if anything else is entered. I thought this would be a good place to learn about handling exceptions and have been referring to [this guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) on how to use try-catch blocks for this purpose.

The problem I've run into is the code (below) seems to be completely ignoring my try block. The reason I think this is that my try block contains the line where the integer "shift" is declared, and when I scroll down to where "shift" is actually used in my code I get a warning saying that "shift cannot be resolved to a variable" and it fails to compile.

Here's the code that's causing the problem, the only difference is that I've enclosed one line within the try block and added a catch block after it that should print an error message (although I've not gotten the code to compile yet so haven't had a chance to play with that and see what it actually does yet).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Shift{

public static void main(String[] args){

    //This will scan for user input.
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Shift by this many characters (0-25): ");

    try {
        int shift = sc.nextInt();
    }
    catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e){
        System.err.println("InputMismatchException: " + e.getMessage());                        
    }

    sc.nextLine();//Skips over the whitespace after the integer
    System.out.print("Enter Text: ");
    String input = sc.nextLine();
    sc.close();

    //Initialise a character array containing every letter in the alphabet. 
    char[] alphabetArray = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m',
                            'n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    char[] alphabetArrayCaps = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M',
                                'N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};

    //Initialise the two variables that will be used in the next step.
    char[] constantArray = input.toCharArray();
    char[] output = input.toCharArray();

    //Implement a Caesar shift by the given number of units.
    for (int i=0; i < constantArray.length; i++){ //cycles through the user input character by character
        for (int j=0; j <= 25; j++){ //cycles through the alphabet
            if (constantArray[i] == alphabetArray[j]){
                    output[i] = alphabetArray[(j+shift)%26];
            }
            else if (constantArray[i] == alphabetArrayCaps[j]){
                        output[i] = alphabetArrayCaps[(j+shift)%26];
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(output);
    }
    }
```

So why does this one small change suddenly stop "shift" from being declared?

Comment: Not giving an answer here, but it would be easier if you changed your char array declaration to `char[] alphabetArray = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray` and `char[] alphabetArrayCaps = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();`

Comment: @itrollin98 I was thinking while I was doing that, there must be an easier way. That's a really great tip, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variables are limited to the scope they are declared in. For more information, see [this nice little tutorial about variable scope in Java](http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2011/02/10/tutorial-java-scjp-10-variable-scope/) (or see [JLS section 6.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3) if you want to get technical, in your case the lines that start with "The scope of a local variable declaration" are relevant).

The simplest explanation of scope is the `{ ... }` pair they are declared in.

In your case:

```
...
try {
    int shift = sc.nextInt();
} ...
```

The variable `shift` is not visible outside the `{ ... }` of that `try` block. You would have to declare it in a higher scope, e.g. as a local variable of the method. However, in the case of a `try` block, if you simply move the declaration outside, you'll still run into a "variable may be used uninitialized" warning because in this:

```
int shift;

try {
    shift = sc.nextInt();
} catch (...) {
    ...
}
```

The code path where `nextInt()` throws an exception can still leave `shift` uninitialized. To resolve that in this case, one option is to just initialize it:

```
int shift = 0;

try {
    shift = sc.nextInt();
} catch (...) {
    ...
}
```

Another option is to ensure it gets a value even if an exception is thrown:

```
int shift;

try {
    shift = sc.nextInt();
} catch (...) {
    shift = 0;
    ...
}
```

A third option is to structure your code in such a way that `shift` is never attempted to be used if an exception is thrown, although this is not quite appropriate for your example (but, for completeness):

```
int shift;

try {
    shift = sc.nextInt();
} catch (Exception x) {
    throw x;
}

// shift can never be used uninitialized here
```

And a fourth option is to structure your code in such a way that `shift` is not needed outside of the `try` block:

```
try {
    int shift = sc.nextInt();
    // do everything that needs to be done with shift here
} catch (...) {
    ...
}

// shift is unneeded here
```

Answer (score 3):

Declare  shift outside of block. Problem is occurring because shift is having scope inside try only. change it as:

```
int shift=0;
try {
    shift = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Note that this would result in a "shift may be used uninitialized" error unless you either initialize it or ensure the `catch` block also gives it a value.

Comment: @JasonC you are absolutely correct. I didn't notice it. I changed it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when you declare a variable inside a try block the scope of that variable is that try block. Once the try block has finished executing all of the variables declared inside the try block will be erased. You need to move the declaration outside of the try block. Like this:

```
int shift = 0;
try {
    shift = sc.nextInt();
}
catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e){
    System.err.println("InputMismatchException: " + e.getMessage());                        
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

In Java, whenever you declare a variable inside a block, you're making what we call a local declaration of that variable. That means the variable is only visible from within the block in which you declared it. In this case, since you declared your `shift` inside the `try` block, it won't be visible from anywhere outside your `try`. What you could do to solve is simply declare it outside the `try` block, like this:

```
int shift;
try {
    shift = sc.nextInt();
}
...
```

You can learn more about scope of declarations in Java here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3